# Unable to locate ajax zone for dynamic update

Tags: ajax, tapestry, zone

I'm fairly new to Tapestry, and I'm trying to update a zone when selecting a value from a select component. This is where I'm trying to do that:

```
    <t:Zone t:id="ispTypeZone" id="ispTypeZone">
                            <t:Select t:id="ispType"
                                t:blankLabel="[${message:select-label}]" t:zone="ispTypeZone"
                                t:value="ispType" event="valueChangedFromIspType"
                                disabled="${editable}" style="width:515px;"
                                t:blankOption="ALWAYS" t:validate="required"
                                />
                                </t:Zone>

    <t:Zone t:id="selectionZone" id="selectionZone">
                            <t:If t:test="${somethingSelected}">

                                <t:If test="${ispSelected}">
                                    <t:Zone t:id="ovZone" id="ovZone">
                                        <t:Select t:id="ovType" t:value="ovType"
                                            t:blankLabel="[${message:select-label}]" t:zone="ovZone"
                                            t:validate="required" event="valueChangedFromOvType"
                                            style="width:515px;" />
                                    </t:Zone>
                                    <p:else>
                                        <t:Zone t:id="vpZone" id="vpZone">
                                            <t:Select t:id="vpType" t:value="vpType"
                                                t:blankLabel="[${message:select-label}]" t:zone="vpZone"
                                                t:validate="required" event="valueChangedFromVpType"
                                                t:blankOption="ALWAYS" disabled="${editable}"
                                                style="width:515px;" />
                                        </t:Zone>
                                    </p:else>
                                </t:If>
                                <p:else>
                                </p:else>

                            </t:If>
                        </t:Zone>
```

This is where I call the render:

```
    void onValueChangedFromIspType(String ispType) {
    //some code here
    if (request.isXHR()) {
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(selectionZone);
    }
    }
```

Whatever the value selected from the select component, it triggers a render for selectionZone, but I keep getting an error message "Unable to locate Ajax Zone 'selectionZone' for dynamic update". Despite the error message, 'somethingSelected' is still being executed, but the following select components are not being displayed. I can't seem to find the problem, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your *ispType* select change have to update something in *selectionZone*, then t:zone should *selectionZone* and not *ispTypeZone*.

In your class, declare your zone :

```
@InjectComponent
private Zone selectionZone;
```

In your onValueChange method a simple return should be enough :

```
 void onValueChangedFromIspType(String ispType) {
//some code here
if (request.isXHR()) {
    return this.selectionZone;
}
}
```